# How to output values with decimal points, without using if statement for printing

Tags: python, floating-point

I want to calculate `a * b / 100` for a set of input values.For Inputs: "37 450" I'm getting "166". But Expected Output is : "166.5"

```
a,b = map(int, input().split())
print(int(a * b / 100))
```

Working Input:

```
45 200
```

Output:

```
90
```

Wrong Input (Answer):

```
37 450
```

Expected Output:

```
166.5
```

Actual Code Output:

```
166
```

If I remove the int() in print statement, I'm getting "0.0" for "0" Output. can we print correctly without using If statement for "0" value output?.

Comment: What is the python version you using?

Comment: When I run your code, I get 0.

Comment: i too get 0 because you have said int(a * b / 100) so the int function will automatically round it to a whole number there is no possibilities of getting a float number

Comment: For Inputs:

37 450

I'm getting 166. But Expected Output is : 166.5

Comment: Do you want decimals for everything except for 0.0? Like 3.6 should be printed as `3.6` and not truncated to `3`? That's what I gather from your title, but the question body doesn't make that clear.

Comment: the answer of the above value is 166.5 but since you have said int(a * b / 100) it will be rounding to the lowest digit and give you a answer of 166

Comment: For `20 50` do you want the output to be `10.0` or `10`? Python will always print at least 1 decimal point, so it's going to print `10.0`. If your question is how to remove the decimal point when it is `.0` please make that clear, cause right now it's confusing what exactly you're asking.

Comment: Of, I got it, If I remove that int() function in print statement, I will get my required Output. But for "0 1000", I'm getting "0.0". I want "0" as output. Can we do that without using If statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Division automatically casts a number to float. So if you want no decimal points in an integer number, just use a if-else block.

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
res = a * b / 100

if int(res) == res:
    print(int(res))
else:
    print(res)
```

Or more simply,

```
print(int(res) if int(res) == res else res)
```

It will print your expected output.

Comment: Can we do it without using if statement, just curious, like using print({:.2f}.format()) for float printing?.

Comment: precision formatting is used when there is a fixed precision point you want.

Comment: For example, 50 will be printed 50.00 and 3.1416 will be printed as 3.14 when you use print({:0.2f}.format())

Answer (score 2):

I see the answer to be outputted as 0 and not 0.0. Please recheck your question. If you see your output to be 0.0, your code must be somewhat as below.

```
a,b = map(int, input().split())
print(int(a) * b / 100)
```

Please recheck and make required correction and let us know of the status of resolution.

Comment: Got it, I just need to remove int() in print statement, and use If statement to print "0.0" as "0". Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following will print the result as a `float`, unless it is `0.0` - then it will print `0`:

```
a,b = map(int, input().split())
result= a * b / 100
if result == 0.0:
    result = int(result)
print(result)
```

Comment: Can we do it without using if statement, just curious, like using print({:.2f}.format()) for float printing?.

Comment: @pop this would not be suited for your case.